# How do you escape underscores and single quotes in Amazon Athena queries?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I would like to run a query like the following on Amazon Athena

```
Select * from my_table
where my_table.my_field like '%'sample_text'%'
```

I want to match the single quotes and the underscore in 'sample_text'.

I've tried variations of escape characters like \_, \\_, [_], `_, and `_` without success.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To escape special characters in `LIKE` use [`ESCAPE`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/comparison.html#like) parameter:

> Wildcard characters can be escaped using the single character specified for the `ESCAPE` parameter.

```sql
WITH dataset (str) AS (
    VALUES ('sample_text '),
    ('sample text ')
)

SELECT *
FROM dataset 
WHERE str like 'sample\_text%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Output:

| str |
| --- |
| sample_text |